# KStreams Determining which input record timestamp metadata is persisted on joins

Tags: java, join, apache-kafka, metadata, apache-kafka-streams

Hopefully someone knows this or can point me in the right direction...

I have a data topic that is created through API REST Requests. One of the fields received in the REST Requests is a timestamp for the record EventTime. These records are produced to Kafka and the EventTime is set as the Record's metadata timestamp.

I have another rules topic that provides information that augments the data topics records by adding new fields to the received value.

Both of these topics having matching keys for joining.

My goal is to preserve the EventTime from the data topic throughout all processing stages using the processor API. Note there will be multiple different KStreams applications that process/augment this data in multiple ways/steps.

The good news is that I have seen many things indicating that input record timestamps are preserved when using Kafka Streams.

Such as:

- https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/streams/core-concepts#streams_time
- [input record timestamp and output record timestamp is same across both source and sink topics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47907174/input-record-timestamp-and-output-record-timestamp-is-same-across-both-source-an)

And have been reading on Timestamp extractors as well:

- [https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/FAQ#FAQ- HowtowriteacustomTimestampExtractor](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/FAQ#FAQ-%20HowtowriteacustomTimestampExtractor)

And more on joining:

- https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Kafka+Streams+Join+Semantics
- https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html#kstream-globalktable-join

Throughout much of the Streams documentation I see it mention that "the timestamp for the input record will persist to the output record" but I am unclear how this works exactly when it comes to joins.

My confusion seems to be that when we join we have 2 different input records and are producing a single output record.

How is it determined which timestamp is persisted between the multiple input records used in the join?

I have been discussing it with coworkers and there have been several views such as the following

- The earliest non negative timestamp of the joined input records is
  persisted.
- The left input record's timestamp is persisted e.g.
  `leftStream.join(rightStream, ...);`
- The timestamp of the input record which triggered the join (left or
  right)
- It's non-Deterministic so the wall-clock-time is used unless a timestamp-extractor is specified for the producer.

Some of these have better arguments then the others but I need the to know what is actually going on...

Any help or suggestions of where to look is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently (ie, Kafka 2.0 release) there is no public contract which timestamp will be used and the implementation is allowed to use any strategy. The current implementation uses the timestamp of the record that triggers the join computation.

As a workaround, you can manipulate the timestamp by adding a `.valueTransformer()` after the join. Compare https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-251%3A+Allow+timestamp+manipulation+in+Processor+API

Ie, you need to embed the original timestamp into the value payload before the join, and extract it after the join and set as metadata timestamp.

Comment: I can't say that is the answer I was hoping for but at least I know where I stand now. Any ideas about if this is likely to change in the future or if it is pretty well cemented at this point? Personally I lean towards the idea of the the left side always persisting since we are joining something to it.

Comment: We do have plans to make a public contract. If this happens, we may do a KIP and will update the docs accordingly. I personally hope to include this in 2.1 -- we started some work for 2.0 already but could not finish it. Personally, I think we should use `max(ts-left, ts-right)` for the output record of stream-stream joins though. The join should be symmetric and compute the same result if you do `stream1.join(stream2)` or `stream2.join(stream1)` -- your proposal would not provide a symmetric join. But as said, it's TDB. Feel free to watch the mailing list and participate -- the beauty of OS.